# Applying CSS to Crystal Reports

Tags: css, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to set CSS class to crystal reports object.

From format object I have set CSS class name to `classname`.

Then I added `classname` elements in aspx page.

The issue I have that object isn't taking the CSS class specifications.

```
<style>
    .classname {
        color: #3E26B5;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>
```

Crystal report viewer

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1"   runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="1202px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelView="None" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="903px" />
<CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
    <Report FileName="Invoice.rpt">
    </Report>
</CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CRPT.SetCssClass(ObjectScope.AllSections,"classname");
```